# How to get Drupal Answer bronze "Announcer" badge?

Tags: support, badges

The [Announcer badge](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer) is described as:

> Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses.

I share link to my question and not my question @ facebook, g+, twitter and nothing.

Comment: Are you sure 25 people visited the link that you shared?

Comment: budget or badge ? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used the links that is shown when you click on the "share" button, and that link was followed by users using 25 unique IP addresses, then you should get the badge.

[image: screenshot]

If you used the normal question link, such as `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/node-access-user-reference` or `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/13605`, then you don't get the badge, as the link doesn't identify who is sharing the link.

The link must then be shared outside Stack Exchange sites, which is what you did.